# Jspdf - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '...\node_modules\jspdf\dist'

Tags: node.js, npm, jspdf

In the `dependencies` portion pf my package.json I have `jspdf` version ^2.3.1, `canvg` version ^4.0.1, `html2canvas` version ^1.3.3, and a few other, unrelated to the issue (I think), packages. In `devDependencies` I have `webpack` version ^5.88.0, `webpack-cli` version ^5.1.4, and `worker-thread` version ^1.1.0.

In the `scripts:build` section, I have `webpack`. My NPM version is 8.3.1 and Node is at version 16.14.0.

When I run `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '...\node_modules\jspdf\dist'
```

What could be the problem here?